# vue-router : how to append another query value to existing query values?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt-link

i have three different **route-link** and i want when you click on each of them ,

a value **query** **added** to **other** queries

```
<router-link append to="{query:{ color : 'red' }" >color</router-link> => ex.com/product?color=red
<router-link append to="{query:{ size: 2 }" >size</router-link> => ex.com/product?color=red&&size=2
<router-link append to="{query:{ men: true }" >men</router-link> => ex.com/product?color=red&&size=2&&men=true
```

the problem is that when you click each of them new query **replace** other

but i want it to append with other queries

so , how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend the existing query object yourself:

```html
<router-link append :to="{ query: { ...$route.query, color: 'red' } }">
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```